# Describe something will be made to do smth in short

Tags: descriptive-grammar

Good day, all!

I'm writing an IT specification for adding a new feature to some existing functionality. Let's say some "sender" plugin will be improved in a way it'll be able to access attributes of items created by some "storage" plugin. So I want to come up with a short title describing the whole new feature and indicate that "something will be able to do something". What grammar form is best applicable here:

1. "Sender plugin to access attributes of items generated by storage plugin"
2. "Sender plugin is to access attributes of items generated by storage plugin"

Are other short forms possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Sender plugin to access attributes of storage plugin items.

Comment: Enable sender access of storage attributes.

Comment: Thank you, guys!